# bootstrap select/form-control with option on Android fails to fire event

Tags: android, jquery, firefox

This is discussing a problem using Bootstrap/jQ on Firefox/Desktop vs Firefox/Android. The handling seems to be different because on Android selecting an list item a select-dialog with all items is shown.

To work (edit/add/delete) with a list of jobs (assume plain text strings) I have this html:
    `<select id="jobsList"  class="form-control" size="10">
       <option>job1</option>
       <option>job2</option>
       <option>job3</option>
    </select>`

I tried to extend `<option></option>` with a `onclick="editSchedule(this)"`. That works fine with FX/desktop with directly accessing the line/option and the called function can work with the job/line. But on Android the separate select-dialog with all 'jobs/lines' shows up. After selecting one, the line in the form is highlighted, but the function isn't called.

Changing to the following jQ code doesn't help:

    `$('#jobsList option').click(function(){
       var job = this.text
       var jIndex =  this.index
       alert('Job selected #:' + jIndex
          +'\nJob:' + job)
    });`

On FX/desktop the alert is fired, not on Android .. so the functions isn't called!
Also using  `$(document).ready(function() {` doesn't help.
Any idea?

Comment: what if you use `$('#jobsList').change` instead of `click`

Comment: @tachyonflux No, doesn't help :>
Also checking for ```$(document).ready(``` again. Inserted an ```alert``` directly after it; so the page loading shows the alert, but not with selecting an ```option``` line, not on desktop, not on Android!